Stylesheet file location does not work when i includes it to another php file
I create a simple book.php file in my root directory with some stylesheet what I linked with link tag. But when I try to include the book.php file into all.php file from root/new directory the stylesheet does not work. It may not find the path properly. I tried with __DIR__ but could not find any solution.
my root/book.php file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo __DIR__?>./stylesheet/new/style.css" />

</head>
<body>

<!--Here some code-->

</body>
</html>

my new file in root/new/all.php directory:
<?php

require_ones(__DIR__."/../book.php");

//some code

?>


If you enable error reporting, or you look in the PHP error logs, you get some feedback on what's wrong.

Typo?  require_ones should be require_once

Also, remember that __DIR__ will give you the filesystem path to the directory containing the current file.  Typically a stylesheet href value would instead be a URL

@Rob-Eyre  It was my typing mistake. require_once i typed but the problem was not solve. But i little bit understand what u are said and try to solve it. Thanks for ur help!

The best way is to put all your CSS, JS, and images into an assets folder and access them using a URL path, not the file system path. For example, instead of using ./stylesheet/new/style.css, use https://example.com/assets/stylesheet/new/style.css

@shirshak007 yeah. Absolutely... Thanks
